# dual version of android support v4 lib facebook sdk eclipse android

Tags: android, facebook, eclipse

I had dual version of android supoort v4 library in facebook lib folder and my android lib folder. I deleted the one from my android and pasted facebook one. Now all my files in android application has resolve error. Like not finding R.layout.main_activity

What should i do ?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning a project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean the "libs" folder because that's where you are supposed to put libraries since ADT 17 then Eclipse will pick them up automatically also if you manually imported the jars in the project properties go in there and remove them. 
Take a look here for a good explanation http://android.foxykeep.com/dev/how-to-fix-the-classdefnotfounderror-with-adt-17

Also try restarting eclipse after you put everything in its place.

Comment: ya in libs folder. removed and out that file again. also in properties had changed my target build of android to 4.2 to 2.2 which was causing that problem particularly. Thanks though !